# Display certain array values

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to arrays and i'm trying to display a certain few.

I've tried var_dump and here's my results

```
array(6) { 
["show_hero_options"]=> string(1) "1" 
["hero_height"]=> string(5) "600px" 
["hero_width"]=> string(4) "100%" 
["hero_buttons"]=> string(4) "show" 
["upload_zzz_link_1"]=> string(105) "http://blahblah.com/image_link.png" 
["upload_zzz_link_2"]=> string(105) "http://blahblah.com/image_link2.png" 
["upload_yyy_link_1"]=> string(79) "http://blahblah.com/image_link3.png"
}
```

Basically I only want to display the values of string 105.

How can I do this?

UPDATE: Sorry to mess you all around, i've just figured out I can't seems to use the string as this seems to change, see this var_dump

```
array(9) { 
["show_hero_options"]=> string(1) "1" 
["hero_height"]=> string(5) "600px" 
["hero_width"]=> string(4) "100%" 
["hero_buttons"]=> string(4) "show" 
["upload_zzz_link_1"]=> string(105) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_zzz_link_2"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_zzz_link_3"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_yyy_link_1"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 

}
```

Basically I want to display all the zzz images, can I do this by and ID or classname?

Comment: Do you want it to display exactly as above, just with fewer entries?

Comment: Hi, i've just updated the question, basically I want to display the zzz images?

Answer (score 1):

This will display every value from the array if the key is 'upload_zzz_link_1' or the length of the value is equal to 105

```
foreach($your_array as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'upload_zzz_link_1') {
        echo $value;
    } elseif(strlen($value) == 105) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $array["upload_zzz_link_1"];
```

Replace `$array` with the name of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$yourArray['upload_zzz_link_1']
```

`105` is a length of the string. So if you want to display strings with length equals `105`, use:

```
foreach ($yourArray as $value) {
  if (strlen($value) != 105) {
    continue;
  }

  var_dump($value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did work but i realised my strings have changed, basically I want to display all the zzz images.

Answer (score 0):

Store the array in a variable:

```
$array = array('your' => 'values');
```

and you can get the value by using its `key`

Like that:

```
echo $array["upload_zzz_link_1"];
```

OR

You can also try using `foreach loop` with `key value pair`

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'upload_zzz_link_1') {  // check here the key which of the value you want
        echo $value;
    } 
}
```